# PHP Radius password sniffing

Tags: php, radius, sniffing

I recently wrote this piece of code:

```
$radius = radius_auth_open();
radius_add_server($radius, $serverIP, $port_no, 'secret', 5, 3);
radius_create_request($radius, RADIUS_ACCESS_REQUEST);
radius_put_attr($radius, RADIUS_USER_NAME, $username);
radius_put_attr($radius, RADIUS_USER_PASSWORD, $password);

$result = radius_send_request($radius);

switch ($result)
{
    case RADIUS_ACCESS_ACCEPT:
    // etc...
```

And my var $password is not encrypted at all, in fact, if I encrypt it with password_hash() radius won't recognize it.

Thus my question is:

Can a sniffer pick up that password? Or does radius_send_request already scramble it because of the parameter RADIUS_USER_PASSWORD?

---

EDIT:

I confused the terms hash and encrypt.

Radius does obfuscate the password when given the parameter attribute RADIUS_USER_PASSWORD.
That is enough security for my system.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you run a sniffer and test it?

Comment: A hash is not an encryption! `password_hash()` hashes a string

Comment: I think you should look at the docs for Radius. If it is a Secure sign in mechanism, you could assume that there would be some sort of handshake between client and server that will negotiate an encryption of the data being passed between cli and server. If not, then probably not. But if you hash your password before passing it to these functions, then it is not going to look like the correct password when it gets to the server, and it compares with its version of your password

Comment: So, do you know what `radius_send_request` does with the data before it sends it to Radius Server or did you assume everything is being sent in plain text to the server? If you aren't familiar with the protocol or functions you use, it might be wise to ensure your assumptions are correct before doing things like hashing passwords randomly.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know how to sniff, now I know.
And Radius does obfuscate the password.
And I switched the terms hash and encrypt because of my native language. sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radius does obfuscate the password when given the parameter attribute RADIUS_USER_PASSWORD.

So nobody should be able to sniff your radius authentication